# solidity delegatecall does not work in another contract

Tags: solidity

I'm trying some codes to find the diff between call and delegatecall.
And I found nither delegatecall nor call did work.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;


contract A{
    address public owner;  // storage
    uint256 counter = 0;

    event addrLog(address _addr, uint256 _counter);

    function getaddr() public returns(address addr){
        addr = address(this);
        owner = addr;


        emit addrLog(owner, ++counter);
    }
}

contract B{
    address public owner; // storage, will used A.owner if A is existed.
    // see a strange usage, I tried bug got compile err, not understanded.
    // address public testAddr = address of A;

    address public testAddr;
    bytes4 public messageId;
    bool public r1;
    bool public r2;

    constructor(address _addressOfCalltest) public {
        testAddr = _addressOfCalltest;
    }

    function testCall() public returns(bool){
        messageId = bytes4(keccak256("getaddr()"));
        return testAddr.call(messageId);
    }

    function testDelegatecall() public returns(bool){
        messageId = bytes4(keccak256("getaddr()"));
        return testAddr.delegatecall(messageId);
    }

    function run() public{
        r1 = testCall();
        r2 = testDelegatecall();
    }
}
```

When I called A.getaddr() in a JS VM, the log is Ok, it dit work.

```
[
    {
        "from": "0xef55bfac4228981e850936aaf042951f7b146e41",
        "topic": "0xff2a5ce99c57a44e471dfcb9313f2cc369b2abf37959acedfbeb720f304545e6",
        "event": "addrLog",
        "args": {
            "0": "0xef55BfAc4228981E850936AAf042951F7b146e41",
            "1": "2",
            "_addr": "0xef55BfAc4228981E850936AAf042951F7b146e41",
            "_counter": "2",
            "length": 2
        }
    }
]
```

However, when I called B.run() or B.testCall() or B.testDelegatecall(), it did not work, the log is null:

```
[]
```

and r1, r2 both changed from false to true, which mean both testAddr.call(messageId) and testAddr.delegatecall(messageId) ran successfully. So my question is why log is null, which means the getaddr() wasn't called actually？

Comment: By the way, anyone who knows the usage of ' address of A'? I found this from an example from someone's blog, I tried, but got compile error.

Answer (score 0):

`testCall()` is working fine. There are some issues with `testDelegatecall()`. To understand why you first need to understand how `delegatecall` works. Here is what is said in [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#delegatecall-callcode-and-libraries):

> There exists a special variant of a message call, named **delegatecall**
>   which is identical to a message call apart from the fact that the code
>   at the target address is executed in the context of the calling
>   contract and `msg.sender` and `msg.value` do not change their values.

What it means that when you are using `.delegatecall()` `getaddr()` will be called as a part of **Contract B**'s function. But as `_counter` does not exits in contract B `log` will contain some garbage value for `_counter`.

Comment: Thanks, bro. Still have 2 questions need to discuss with you, waiting for your feedback, thanks a lot. Because the comments is length limit, so I post my question as an answer as below. Would you feedback sometime? Thanks

Comment: Thanks lftifar Taz, I tried and found out the fact.  When I deployed contract B, I need give the address of contract A, so testCall() could call A.getaddr(), while before I always gave a random address, which called "unknow contract", so actually testCall() called "unknow contract".getaddr(), this is why testCall() did not work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In **Contract B**'s `constructor` you are taking an address as parameter. So i assumed it is the address of **Contract A**.

Comment: Emm..I am green hand in solidity, hop that I could learn more day by day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@lftifar Taz, thanks.

Q1: As you said, I modify contract B as below,

```
contract B{
    address public owner; 
    address public testAddr;
    bytes4 public messageId;
    bool public r1;
    bool public r2;

    uint256 counter = 0;
    ...
}
```

compile & ran testCall again, the log was still [].

Q2: function getaddr() is to return address of a contract;
    Expected that when testCall was called, return address of contract A, expected A.owner is the address of A, but it's 0x00;
    Expected that when testDelegatecall was called, return address of contract B(not A), expected B.owner is the address of B, but it's 0x00;

This is why I suspected that getaddr was not called by testCall or testDelegatecall at all, 
and that's why I added log printing for getaddr. But now I'am more confused.

Comment: **A1.** You also need to add the `event addrLog(address _addr, uint256 _counter);` in **Contract B**. And for some reason adding `uint256 counter = 0;` after `address public testAddr;` doesn't work. I don't have any answer to that. **A2.** `getaddr()` changes the `state` of the **contract** hence it will always return a transaction hash. You can't return any value from `getaddr()`